# Need Help Filtering Data - Google Sheets (see explanation)

Tags: filter, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

So the problem is I have 200 machines installation which I have to track the progress.

I have set up a form to get all the information I need and the basic thing I need to know is which items of a list are "NOT OK", so I'd like to filter them with a macro or something.

[image: I guess what I want is better explained here]

I am using google sheets: 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/134MVv30n-sMOUbuquMIno1zZEBvt2wpnrU_UJhYrp4o/edit?usp=sharing

I've been trying all day (seriously) but I'm definitely not used to working with spreadsheets. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for each machine it would be like this:

#### `MACHINE 1`

```
=FILTER({$A4:$A \ B4:B}; B4:B="Not Ok")
```

#### `MACHINE 2`

```
=FILTER({$A4:$A \ C4:C}; C4:C="Not Ok")
```

#### `MACHINE 3`

```
=FILTER({$A4:$A \ D4:D}; D4:D="Not Ok")
```

etc...

[image: 0]

---

but you should consider the advantage of this structure:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SORT(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRIM(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(B4:E24="not ok"; "♠"&A4:A24&"♦"&B3:E3&"♦"&B27:E27; ))
 ;;999^99));;999^99)); "♠")); "♦"); 2; 1))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Hey @player0 ! Thank you so much for taking the time to help me :) I really liked the solution you proposed!

I only have 2 questions:

1)Would it be Possible to place the info like this: 
Machine | Field | DATE| SMS 
Still grouped by machine as you did but sorted by date

2) Is there a way this could be automated for N number or machines? I only included 3 on my sampletable but its going to be 200+ of them... 

I would really like to do both things on my own but I dont really know ANYTHING about this so I'm really grateful with what you've done.

Comment: answer is yes for both of your questions. you can keep appending fields you need in this string in the similar matter - `"♠"&A4:A24&"♦"&B3:E3&"♦"&B27:E27`- also this includes 4 machines coz range is B-E so for 200+ machines you just increase the ranges to fit your needs

Comment: Two questions more: I have set up the code to show the date as well, but instead of getting the date i'm getting a random number on that field :( `=ARRAYFORMULA(SORT(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRIM(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(B4:E24="not ok"; "♠"&B3:E3&"♦"&A4:A24&"♦"&B26:E26&"♦"&B27:E27; ))
 ;;999^99));;999^99)); "♠")); "♦");1;2))`  I also wanted to ask you what are `999^99));;999^99` those for?

Comment: Hey @player0 is my last question bro! Promise! Hahahaha So the final code we were using was: `=ARRAYFORMULA(SORT(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRIM(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE( IF(TRANSPOSEDDATA!B4:E24="not ok"; "♠"&TRANSPOSEDDATA!B3:E3&"♦"&TRANSPOSEDDATA!B26:E26&"♦"&TRANSPOSEDDATA!A4:A24&"♦"&TRANSPOSEDDATA!B27:E27; )) ;;999^99));;999^99)); "♠")); "♦");3;1))` That is filtering for "not ok" is it possible to make it filter for "Unsure" aswell? AND Is it possible for it to show on the table what the finding was? So the final output MACHINE | DATE | FIELD | NOTOK/UNSURE | SMSINSPECTOR.... Thank you!

Comment: `=ARRAYFORMULA(SORT(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRIM(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE( IF((TRANSPOSEDDATA!B4:E24="not ok")+(TRANSPOSEDDATA!B4:E24="unsure"); "♠"&TRANSPOSEDDATA!B3:E3&"♦"&TRANSPOSEDDATA!B26:E26&"♦"&TRANSPOSEDDATA!A4:A24&"♦"&TRANSPOSEDDATA!B4:E24&"♦"&TRANSPOSEDDATA!B27:E27; )) ;;999^99));;999^99)); "♠")); "♦");2;1))`

Comment: Hi! @player0 I hope you are doing great. Hey... So I finally got my whole database setup with all 306 machines and 90 questions and tried modifýing the array with no success at all :( Would you mind helping me again? I have left the previous NORMAL LOGS, TRANSPOSED DATA, and PREVIOUS ARRAY (Which worked, for reference) and well the new data and transposed data. I Tried modifiing the array formula but get an error...  Please Help me :(

Comment: `=ARRAYFORMULA(SORT(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRIM(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE( IF((NEWTRANSPOSEDDATA!B4:KU90="not ok")+(NEWTRANSPOSEDDATA!B4:KU90="unsure"); "♠"&NEWTRANSPOSEDDATA!B2:KU2&"♦"&NEWTRANSPOSEDDATA!B3:KV3&"♦"&NEWTRANSPOSEDDATA!A4:A90&"♦"&NEWTRANSPOSEDDATA!B4:KU90&"♦"&NEWTRANSPOSEDDATA!B93:KU93; )) ;;999^99));;999^99)); "♠")); "♦");1;3))`

Comment: Hey! @player0 Thank you very much. I am not sure on what i did wrong but now it works. Hey I am wonrdering if something I have in mind can be done.... Is it possible to set up a filter for 6 different columns in which: filter (column 1= not empty or column2 not empty or column 3 notempty... ) So that it retrieves only the rows that have something filled put at any of the columns, whether all of them are filled or only one of them is?

Comment: you had a typo. instead 999^99 you used 999^999 which is too big and resulted into error. regarding your filter question... it's possible

Comment: OK I'll try to do this one: So similar array, displaying Machine Name | Column 1l Column 5|...Column6| Inspector but it will only print the machines that have at least one of the columns with some data in it. Is it better if I use it with columns or rows?

Comment: well, no idea. the sheet is private so I can see nothing :)

Comment: Yikes here is the new link...https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E1InzKtPXlJKGJEyWgrg4OzeFdRoZ_wBw1Xu_mdMT4c/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I cannot send PM's Yet because im still considered a new user here but heres the link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1B-3wyJBf-FFNsx1GyAuHT9kfvEjg5Vn9tzwGratq80E/edit?usp=sharing    Thank you once again!

Comment: Hi, @player0 I am very sorry I had to go to the hospital, a friend of mine got his knee hurt and had an Emergency Surgery and needed someone to sign the papers so I had to go. Sorry for leaving you there. I am very grateful with the help provided. Right now I cant chat with you but Ill reach you during the week so I can Know what how you solved it.... I tried to get back to you just now, but you werent there anymore.... Thank you a lot. -Sergio

Comment: BTW @player0 Sent you a very small, but symbolic thank you on paypal. I am not aware on food prices where you live, but I hope that may bring a nice plate for dinner to your table :)